# How to print group name in the group header section when group name is the same on next page, but do not print totals

Tags: jasper-reports

How to print group name in the group header section when group name is the same on next page, but do not print totals

In iReport I checked property "Reprint header" in order to print group header field name if next page comes with same group field name. But the same time I don't want to print totals for same group name.

When checked "Reprint header" property report print me group field name (by which it was grouped) and same time totals.

How can I suppress totals amount for the same group field name, another words totals amount shouldn't be displayed in report.

In the attached second image highlighted total numbers shouldn't be printed.

Thank you.[image: first page with group header name and totals][image: second page where totals shouldn't be printed if second page with same group name.]

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

1. Reprint header for the header group band should be checked.
2. Print When Expression for each total/summary field in group header band should be assigned with iReport COUNT variable, i.e.

$V{Phase Code_COUNT}==0